# ibatis - cannot set cacheModel

Tags: ibatis, ibatis.net

I want to set cacheModel on an insert and i do it like this:

```
<select id="SelectAll_Cache" resultClass="SN" cacheModel="cache-select-all">
    <include refid="GetAll_SN"/>
</select>

<cacheModel id="cache-select-all" implementation="LRU" readOnly="false" serialize="true">
    <flushInterval hours="24"/>
    <property name="size" value="800"/>
</cacheModel>
```

If i execute the query i get the following exception:

- The error occurred while Set CacheModel to statement.
- statement : SelectAll_Cache
- The error occurred in cacheModel : SN.cache-select-all.

Comment: Problem Solved : there must be a <cacheModels> tag and all <cacheModel> tags inside

Comment: If you found the answer, then post it as an aswer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the cache model before you use it.

You should define cache model in your sql map before using it in the select statements;then only ibatis sql map parser should be able to find the cache model that you'r using in your statement.